# How to update Office 2016 to Office 2019?

Tags: office365, microsoft-office-2019

I saw that the version of Office 2019 came out, I have Office 365 ProPlus:

[image: My office suscription]

I was interested in updating, I tried through **File> Account> Update Options> Update Now**, it says that I have the latest version but when clicking About Word I still have the 2016 version:

[image: My microsoft word version]

Then I tried to download the installer again from [aka.ms/office-install](http://aka.ms/office-install), 
when the installation finished I still had the same version.

So my questions are:

- Does the license I have gives me access to the 2019 version?
- Or is the update still not available for my language or country
  (Mexico)?
- Or is there another option that I can follow to update?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I also followed the steps of the following [url](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-365-or-office-2019-on-a-pc-or-mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658?omkt=en-001&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)

Comment: The first thing you need to do is install the current version of Word (1809).  You can do the by running the update from within Word (simplest way).

Comment: It is not clear which version you have installed.  If you have 1809 then you have all Offie 2019 features already.  Office 2019 is for anyone, who wants a single point in time release build, forever.

Comment: The office subscription versions already include the features available in Office 2019. Office 2016 and Office 2019 are the one-time-purchase versions of the Office software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the license I have gives me access to the 2019 version?

Yes;  However, it appears your organization and/or school Administrator has configured your account to only receive Semi-Annual Channel builds.  This means you will eventually get the Office features that exist within Office 2019.  This would happen around March 2019 for the Semi-Annual Channel.

Version 1809 is indeed Office 2019, any features added to Office, will be in future builds of Office that are unique to Office 365.  The retail build information for Office 2019 confirms that Office 2019, is indeed Version 1809

[image]

[image]

Source:

- [Update history for Office 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2019)
- [Release notes for Monthly Channel releases in 2018](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/monthly-channel-2018#version-1809-october-9)

> Or is the update still not available for my language or country (Mexico)?

It is indeed available for your country.  Office 365 subscribers received,  the changes that are included in the Office 2019, changes a while ago.  You likely have a few of the features, that exist within 1803, that are a subset of those that exist within Office 2019

> Office 2019 (for both Windows and Mac) is a one-time purchase and does
>   not receive feature updates after you purchase it. Office 2019
>   includes a meaningful subset of features that are found in Office 365,
>   but it's not part of Office 365. Office 2019 will receive quality and
>   security updates as required.
>
> Office 365 is a user-based subscription service powered by the
>   Microsoft cloud. It provides access to a suite of services beyond what
>   the on-premises version has and receives feature updates on an ongoing
>   basis. It includes the most productive, secure, and up-to-date
>   features.

Additionally

> **If I have Office 365, do I need to get Office 2019?**
>
> No. Office 365 is our always-up-to-date version of the Office apps,
>   and subscribers already have a version of Office that has all the
>   functionality that's in Office 2019 and more. See a comparison of
>   Office 365 ProPlus and Office 2019.

Source: [Office 2019 Commercial for Windows and Mac frequently asked questions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4133312/office-2019-commercial-for-windows-and-mac-frequently-asked-questions)

> Or is there another option that I can follow to update?

With your current configuration, you will have to wait, until 1809 is released to the Semi-Annual Channel.  However, in order to determine what build you are running do the following actions.

> 1. Open any Office application, such as Word or Excel, and select Account.
> 2. Under Product Information, you'll find your Office product name and, in some cases, the full version number.

[image]

> 1 - Product name, such as Office 365 ProPlus or Office Home and
>   Student.
>
> 2 - Version number, which includes version, build number, and the type
>   of installation such as Click-to-run or Windows Store.

[What version of Office am I using?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-office-what-version-of-office-am-i-using-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19)

> I was interested in updating, I tried through File> Account> Update Options> Update Now, it says that I have the latest version but when clicking About Word I still have the 2016 version.

If you are not being offered Version 1809 then your Administrator has simply not made it [available](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-the-Standard-or-Targeted-release-options-in-Office-365-3b3adfa4-1777-4ff0-b606-fb8732101f47) to you.  Based on the information provided by your screenshot it appears you are on the Semi-Annual Channel and are running 1803.

[image]

Sources

- [Release information for updates to Office 365 ProPlus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-notes-office365-proplus)
- [Update history for Office 365 ProPlus (listed by date)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that even though it may show office 2016 or 365, it doesn't matter. What matters, is the version that is version 2104(the latest version as if right now I am typing this text), etc.

If you have the latest version of the office installed you will have all the features present in the latest version which as of right now I am typing this text it is 2019.

I too was confused but when I checked the features present in the latest version of the office and compared them to the features I had in my office. I had all the latest features which were even present in office 2019. And I know this is late but I just want to help.

Thank you

Comment: **This is incorrect.** Word in Office 365 has features not available in Word 2016 or Word 2019. Word 2019 has features not available in Word 2016. This is true even though they will all show the same version number and build. Microsoft started doing this update plan about two years ago and it can be very confusing. --- The first answer is correct. Microsoft 365 includes all the features in Office 2019 and more.

Answer (score -1):

Not required to 2016 -> 2019 update beacuse Office 2016 / 2019 /2021 version is one-time purchase.

Office 365 subscription version is always monthly new feature update as Current Channel / Current Channel (Preview) / Beta Channel.

Credit link [one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-the-difference-between-microsoft-365-and-office-2021-ed447ebf-6060-46f9-9e90-a239bd27eb96) and [two](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date).

Comment: This doesn’t actually answer the authors question

Comment: @Ramhound OK , I post sure answer to 1. Purchase genuine latest Microsoft Office version with [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/p/office-home-student-2021/cfq7ttc0h8n8?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). 2. Clean unistall old Microsoft Office version with Office Tool Plus in [link](https://github.com/YerongAI/Office-Tool/releases). 3. Install latest Microsoft Office and experience genuine Microsoft Office version.