# MS-Office 2019 how to stop syncing to onedrive

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, sync, onedrive, microsoft-office-2019

Yesterday I uninstalled Office 2016 and installed 2019. I installed only Word/Excel, and no other apps (not OneDrive).

When I run Word/Excel - Open, it still shows OneDrive and my email is there:

[image: OneDrive in Microsoft Word]

I hadn't even installed OneDrive, let alone signing in to that, so I didn't even gave my OneDrive password to Office 2019, how it reached there? 
Probably it didn't uninstall office 2016 fully and picked my settings from that.

Now, OneDrive is not installed, so I can't install it.

Office 2019 apps modify/change is showing only repair/uninstall, and not showing individual components add/remove, as it was showing in previous offices, so I can't see whether it got installed, and to uninstall that if installed.

Clicking on the above OneDrive brings up a screen with several folders that is shown located at https://d.docs.live.net/nnnnnnnnnnnnnn in Windows Explorer where 'nnn' are alphanumeric characters.

There is no option appearing in ms word to disconnect syncing to OneDrive or to logout of it.

My Windows 10 is indeed logged in to Microsoft Live and is syncing. I don't know whether that brings OneDrive.

I work on clients' files, and some clients have strongly worded Non-Disclosure Agreement stating that I am not to put/share their files on the Internet.  So, I am worried that some hacking might get my clients' material stolen and I will be in deep trouble.

How can I stop Microsoft Office from syncing to OneDrive?

OneDrive should not be visible to me anywhere within Microsoft Office.

Software versions:

- Windows 10 x64 1809
- Microsoft Office 2019 Standard 11126.20226

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I installed only Word/ Excel, and none other apps (not OneDrive)

OneDrive is installed by default by Windows 10.  You might want to verify you don't actually have it installed since it can be removed, but that isn't the focus of this question.  Even if you disable the OneDrive Windows 10 client, I don't believe it's required, for the OneDrive functionality within Office.  Additionally, only OneDrive Business is installed by Office which is slightly different than the built-in OneDrive client on Windows 10.

> when I run word/ excel - Open, it still shows OneDrive and my email is there.

This is due to the fact you are actually logged into your Microsoft account.

> I hadn't even installed OneDrive, let alone signing in to that, so I didn't even give my OneDrive password to Office 2019, how it reached there?

OneDrive is installed by default on Windows 10.  OneDrive is connected to your Microsoft Account, which you are clearly logged into since you removed your account information from your screenshot.

> Probably it didn't uninstall office 2016 fully and picked my settings from that.

Office 2016 and Office 2019 can exist on the same system, although this will cause problems, with applications like iCloud.  In any event, the settings between the two applications, are actually indeed separate.

> There is no option appearing in ms word to disconnect syncing to OneDrive or to logout of it.

There wasn't an option to remove the OneDrive, from the list of locations, where a file can be saved in Office 2016.  However, if you log out of your account, it will find you will be asked to log into your account before a file can be saved to that location.

> here is no option appearing in ms word to disconnect syncing to OneDrive or to sign out of it.

There absolutely is an option to sign out of your Microsoft Account within Office.  However, based on the build you actually have installed, you have Office 365 installed instead of Office 2019 (which is a specific Office 365 build from October 2018).  **Office 2019 is identical to Office 365 except you don't get incremental monthly builds with an Office 2019 license.**  [This is all documented by Microsoft, and I have already spent hours researching it and submitting an answer to that very topic.](https://superuser.com/questions/1366095/how-to-update-office-2016-to-office-2019/1366106#1366106)

[image]

> work on clients' files, and some clients have strongly worded
>   Non-Discloser Agreement stating that I am not to put/ share their
>   files on net. so, I am worried that some hacking might get my clients'
>   material stolen and I will be in deep trouble.

You should just change the default location.

> 1. Click the File tab, and then click Options.
> 2. Click Save.
> 3. In the first section, type the path in the Default local file location box
>
> [image]

[Set a default working folder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-a-default-working-folder-786200a7-f5f2-4d26-a3ae-b78c60dd5d3b)

> how to stop MS office syncing to onedrive. Onedrive should not be visible to me anywhere within MS Office.

OneDrive is now intergrated into Office and it cannot be removed.  It has been intergrated since I believe Office 2013.  The only new change is the default location.

> Starting as early as next month, Microsoft plans to change Office 365's default document-saving behavior to OneDrive and OneDrive for Business folder locations.

[OneDrive To Become Office 365's Default 'Save' Location](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-a-default-working-folder-786200a7-f5f2-4d26-a3ae-b78c60dd5d3b)

Answer (score 1):

File tab, options, save.  Next to the default path is a checkbox that says 'Save to computer by default'.  Click that.

Even if you designate the default path as a local path, unless you check that box Office will try and push One Drive as the default location.  I got that answer from MS through several attempts at tech support, Dec 2019.

This will not remove One Drive from personal storage options in Office but it will stop the default One Drive save location.  You can't remove one drive from Office.