# How can Office 365 detect my work account

Tags: office365, microsoft-office-2019

So I have an Office 365 home subscription registered to my private gmail. I recently wanted to try out Office 2019 so I installed Office 2019 in a virtual machine and loged in with my gmail.

I was surprised to see that as soon as I logged in my work accounts appeared in the "accounts" menu. We do have Office 365 at work and I am a global admin in that O365 tenant.

[image]

My question is, how is my Office 365 Home subscription able to detect my work account when I did not enter any of my work account credentials in the VM?

As you probably can imagine I would like to keep my work account and my private account separated.

Comment: You do know that if you have an Office 365 subscription then you already had Office 2019 installed in fact, the build you would have had installed, would have been newer than the Office 2019 build.  Based on the screenshot that is exactly what happens.  1904 is not Office 2019 it's a recent build of Office 365.  I did a massive amount of research on this subject [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1366095/how-to-update-office-2016-to-office-2019?rq=1) it might be helpful.\

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that was besides the question though.

Comment: Your Microsoft account must be linked to your Office account in some capacity.  You could just hit `Remove Service` at this point though.  You are not currently logged into your Office account though.